# Wordpress permissions Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, chmod

I moved my WP installations from Centos 6 to Ubuntu 16.04.

I cannot update Wordpress using a separate user for each website.

I set the following permissions:

```
find /home/mysite -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find /home/mysite -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find /home/mysite -exec chown mysite:www-data {} \;
```

But the only way WP will update is if I set the `chown` to `www-data`:

```
find /home/mysite -exec chown www-data {} \;
```

I have several WP projects on one server and one IP with separate domain names:

```
/home/mysite1
/home/mysite2
/home/mysite3
```

Is it safe to operate them all under `www-data`?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer
make the wp-content directory owned by www-data and ad this line to the end of wp-config

```
define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');
```